# Add three numbers with textBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, addition

I have a textbox1 two and three. In textbox1 number zero, in two number one and in three number two and use this code

```
textBox4.Text = "" + 
  (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 
  (int.Parse(textBox2.Text + 
  (int.Parse(textBox3.Text)))));
```

but result is 012..you can have the entire amount, 3?

Comment: ... where is the question ? So basically you are getting sum of the strings here : (textBox2.Text + (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) , and it's "12" then you parse it to int (12) and sum with 0 -> 12 and then you sum it with "" and get "12". So your result is not "012", your result is "12", if you want to sum integers then you need to parse before sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int result = 
  int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 
  int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + 
  int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
textBox4.Text = result.ToString();
```

Try this

Comment: if 1 textbox is null this code will give an error.. how can we let the user to keep a textbox empty

Comment: check before summing:
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the sum is being evaluated from left to right and this is causing a different type of addition to be performed than what you would expect.  In C#, you can add two strings.  If you add `"foo"` to `"bar"` then this will give you the string `"foobar"`.  If you add a string and a number together, then it will convert the number to a string and add the two strings together.  So `"foo"+13` yields `"foo13"`.

So what's happening in your example is quite complicated.  Starting from the inside, you have: `int.Parse(textBox3.Text)`.  This takes `textBox3.Text` which is `"2"` and converts it to the number `2`.  Next you do `textBox2.Text + (int.Parse(textBox3.Text)` which gets the string `"1"` and then adds the number 2 to it.  This causes the number `2` to be converted to the string `"2"` and then adds `"1"+"2"`, giving the string `"12"` as the answer since strings are added by joining them.  Next you do `int.Parse(textBox2.Text + (int.Parse(textBox3.Text))` which converts the string `"12"` to the number `12`.  You also do `int.Parse(textBox1.Text)` which gives the number `0`.  So at this point you're adding `"" + 0 + 12`.  It does this from left to right, first adding `""` to `0`.  This causes `0` to be converted to `"0"` and `"" + "0"` gives `"0"`.  Then we are adding `"0" + 12`.  When we do this, `12` gets converted to `"12"` and `"0"+"12"` gives `"012"`.

Without making big changes, you could get the correct result just by changing your parentheses.  If the numbers were all added together before any of them are added to strings, then you'll get the correct result.  We can accomplish this with parentheses.

```
textBox4 = "" + (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + int.Parse(textBox3.Text));
```

In short, it's really important to pay attention to what's happening in what order and what the types are because adding two strings is completely different from adding two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Put the " mark at the end that way it does the regular math first, then the string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can you smth like this:

```
int sum=int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
textBox4.Text = String.Format("{0}",sum);
```

Comment: Or you can use some parser if you need complex equations in future
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MathParserLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here. The first one is the "" at the beginning. When you do the first +, textBox1.Text is first parsed, then converted to string again by the string concatenating operator. I'd prefer something like this:

```
textBox4.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + int.Parse(textBox3.Text)).ToString();
```

The second problem (the real one) is the fact that you miss a closing parenthesis after textBox2.Text. In this way you are first concatenating textBox1.Text ("1") and int.Parse(textBox2.Text).ToString() ("2"), and only at this point you parse the result. If the parenthesis were not missing your code would give "3" and not "012"

Comment: Ogni tanto un italiano grazie per la risposta =)

Comment: Già che ci siamo, se non hai messo vincoli sulle TextBox io userei TryParse al posto di Parse, così sei sicuro di non generare eccezioni

Comment: ma non mi conviene ho la somma che si trova gia sotto un try e un if purtroppo è una questione difficile da spiegare